# Convert date format in Scala

Tags: scala, date

I am trying to convert a date format of that looks like this:
2011-09-30 00:00:00.0
to 20110930 
in scala. 
Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at `java.text.DateFormat`

Comment: But can I write some code that would do this? I am trying to add this to a script that will ultimately search for the min and max of my dates..

Comment: Yes. Actrually, using `SimpleDateFormat` looks better. You'll create a `SimpleDateFormat` class passing in the pattern to represent your date format, parse it, then you can convert each one to milliseconds to find the min and max.

Comment: You don't need to `format()` multiple dates into a common `String` format in order to compare them and find min or max. You can do that directly on the `Date` elements after you `parse()` the input strings.

Answer (score 6):

Use something like this:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

val inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S")
val outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy")

val date = "2015-01-31 12:34:00.0"
val formattedDate = outputFormat.format(inputFormat.parse(date))

println(formattedDate) //20150131
```

Answer (score 5):

If all you want to do is to change date format from string to string all you may do something similar to:

```
def toSimpleDate(dateString: String): Option[String] = {
  val parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S")
  val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd")

  Try {
    LocalDateTime.parse(dateString, parser)
  }.toOption
    .map(_.format(formatter))
}

toSimpleDate("2011-09-30 00:00:00.0") // Some("20119030")
toSimpleDate("Meh") // None
```

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use the Date Functions as mentioned in other answers. However if you are sure about the format to be `2011-09-30 00:00:00.0`

A simple Map operation should be fine

```
val x = List("2011-09-30 00:00:00.0")
val output = x map (x => x.dropRight(11).replace("-",""))
> output: List[String] = List(20110930)
```

However this solution works **If and Only If** You can guarantee the input comes in the same format.