# How to change date from yyyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yyy using Spark function

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark

I'm working on Apache spark project on eclipse using Scala

I would like to change my date format from `yyyy-mm-dd` to `dd-mm-yyyy`

This is my code:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("trying")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf) 
val x = 
sc.textFile("/home/amel/1MB")
.filter(!_.contains("NULL")).filter(!_.contains("Null"))

val re = x.map(row => {
val cols = row.split(",")
val Cycle = cols(2)
val Duration = Cycle match {
case "Licence" => "3 years"
case "Master" => "2 years"
case "Ingéniorat" => "5 years"
case "Ingeniorat" => "5 years"
case "Doctorat" => "3 years"
case _ => "NULL" }
(cols(0)+","+cols(1) + "," + Cycle + "," +  cols(3) + "," 
+Duration)
})
re.collect.foreach(println)
```

This is an example of the result I got:

```
0000023497,2007-06-27,Master,SI,2 years
```

This is what I want my result to look like

```
0000023497,27-06-2007,Master,SI,2 years
```

Comment: yes, its a french word

Comment: Date parsing/formatting in Scala is usually done with `java.time`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480633/java-util-date-format-conversion-yyyy-mm-dd-to-mm-dd-yyyy) is a close example.

Comment: I'm using Scala not Java.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.util.Date format conversion yyyy-mm-dd to mm-dd-yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480633/java-util-date-format-conversion-yyyy-mm-dd-to-mm-dd-yyyy)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert date format in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48411565/convert-date-format-in-scala)

Comment: Not a duplicate because of "using spark functions" clause in the question. Thanks.

Comment: In this case: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348168/converting-pattern-of-date-in-spark-dataframe. Also the OP doesn't seem to be using a dataframe, which makes the other duplicates/solutions valid.

Comment: @XavierGuihot I agree. Duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348168/converting-pattern-of-date-in-spark-dataframe

Answer (score 3):

Can be done with regex.

```
val ymd = raw"(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)".r

ymd.replaceAllIn("2007-06-27", m => s"${m group 3}-${m group 2}-${m group 1}")
//res0: String = 27-06-2007
```

Can also be done via `java.time` library formatting.

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

LocalDate.parse("2019-01-04")
         .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"))
//res1: String = 04-01-2019
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.date_format` function

Example:

```
scala> df.show
+----------+
|      date|
+----------+
|2019-06-25|
|2019-06-26|
|2019-06-27|
+----------+

scala> df.withColumn("date2", org.apache.spark.sql.functions.date_format($"date", "dd-MM-yyyy")).show
+----------+----------+
|      date|     date2|
+----------+----------+
|2019-06-25|25-06-2019|
|2019-06-26|26-06-2019|
|2019-06-27|27-06-2019|
+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `Scala 2.13` alternative via pattern matching by [unapplying a string interpolator](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/StringContext$s$.html#unapplySeq(s:String):Option[Seq[String]]):

```
"2007-06-27" match { case s"$year-$month-$day" => s"$day-$month-$year" }
// "27-06-2007"
```